# Clojure recur's strange behavior

Tags: recursion, clojure, tail-recursion

I have written a simple function in Clojure which can parse XML:

```
(defn filter-tags [xml & selectors]
  (if (and (seq selectors) (seq xml))
    (recur         
      (->>      
        xml
        (filter #(= (first selectors) (:tag %)))
        (map :content)
        flatten)
      (rest selectors))
  xml))

(defn search-twitter [query]
  (->
    (clojure.xml/parse (str "http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=" query))
    :content
    (filter-tags :entry :title)))

(first (search-twitter "something")))
```

It works well with recur...but it's strange, when I try to do the "plain" recursion, explicitly calling the filter-tags, it doesn't work...
Could somebody explain this?

Comment: define "doesn't work" - no output or crash with stacktrace?

Comment: It returns nil, as I remember well (I use Clojure 1.2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use `apply` (because the parameter `selectors` make the function variadic) to call the function using plain recursion as shown below:

```
(defn filter-tags [xml & selectors]
  (if (and (seq selectors) (seq xml))
    (apply filter-tags         
      (->>      
        xml
        (filter #(= (first selectors) (:tag %)))
        (map :content)
        flatten)
      (rest selectors))
  xml))
```

Or make it non variadic then your normal recursion call will work